# Display multiple queries with different row types as one result

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, procedure

In PostgreSQL 8.3 on Ubuntu, I do have 3 tables, say T1, T2, T3, of different schemas.
Each of them contains (a few) records related to the object of the ID I know.
Using 'psql', I frequently do the 3 operations:

```
SELECT field-set1 FROM T1 WHERE ID='abc';

SELECT field-set2 FROM T2 WHERE ID='abc';

SELECT field-set3 FROM T3 WHERE ID='abc';
```

and just watch the results; for me it is enough to see.

Is it possible to have a procedure/function/macro etc, with one parameter 'id',
just running the three SELECTS one after another,
displaying results on the screen ?

field-set1, field-set2 and field-set 3 are **completely different**.

There is no reasonable way to JOIN the tables T1, T2, T3; these are unrelated data.
I do not want JOIN.
I want to see the three resulting sets on the screen.

Any hint?

Comment: Do you need a _pure_ database solution (like [SQL UNION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION)) or is an external script that connects to the database and runs the three queries also ok?

Answer (score 2):

#### Quick and dirty method

If the row types (data types of all columns in sequence) don't match, `UNION` will fail.
However, in PostgreSQL you can *cast a whole row* to its `text` representation:

```
SELECT t1:text AS whole_row_in_text_representation FROM t1 WHERE id = 'abc'

UNION ALL
SELECT t2::text FROM t2 WHERE id = 'abc'

UNION ALL
SELECT t3::text FROM t3 WHERE id = 'abc';
```

Only one `;` at the end, and the one is optional with a single statement.

---

#### A more refined alternative

But also needs a lot more code. Pick the table with the most columns first, cast every individual column to text and give it a generic name. Add `NULL` values for the other tables with fewer columns. You can even insert headers between the tables:

```
SELECT '-t1-'::text AS c1, '---'::text AS c2, '---'::text AS c1  -- table t1
UNION ALL
SELECT '-col1-'::text, '-col2-'::text, '-col3-'::text  -- 3 columns
UNION ALL
SELECT col1::text, col2::text, col3::text FROM t1 WHERE id = 'abc'

UNION ALL
SELECT '-t2-'::text, '---'::text, '---'::text  -- table t2
UNION ALL
SELECT '-col_a-'::text, '-col_b-'::text, NULL::text  -- 2 columns, 1 NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT col_a::text, col_b::text, NULL::text FROM t2 WHERE id = 'abc'

...
```

Answer (score 1):

put a `union all` in between and name all columns equal

```
 SELECT field-set1 as fieldset FROM T1 WHERE ID='abc';
 union all
 SELECT field-set2 as fieldset FROM T2 WHERE ID='abc';
 union all
 SELECT field-set3 as fieldset FROM T3 WHERE ID='abc';
```

and execute it at once.

Comment: That was also my first thought, but I think the OPs problem is that field-set 1-3 consist of a different number of columns with different data types.